# Set max result to octobercms repeater

Tags: octobercms

I have the bellow repeater

```
{repeater name="gallery" prompt="Add another image" tab="Gallery"}
{variable type="mediafinder" name="image" label="Image" type="mediafinder" mode="image"}{/variable}
{variable type="text" name="title" label="Title"}{/variable}
{variable type="text" name="description" label="Description"}{/variable}
{variable type="richeditor" name="button" label="Button Link" toolbarButtons="insertLink" size="small"}{/variable}
{/repeater}
```

Can I set max result of repeats?

For example if set max=3 repeats of gallery. Whenever reach the amount of 3 the prompt "Add another image" does not appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature does not exist at the moment. The best place to request it is the [October CMS GitHub issues register](https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues), or better yet, you could submit a Pull Request for it to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Add a limiter, for example 3:

```
maxItems="3"

{repeater name="gallery" prompt="Add another image" tab="Gallery" maxItems="3"}
```